# Segmentation fault while trying to test fgets()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm trying to write a program to experiment with the fgets() function, with which I have little experience. I keep getting a segmentation fault 11 error when I run the program (but no errors when I compile it) and I don't know enough about fgets to know what is going on. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("wageData.txt","r+");
    char x[3][5];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        fgets(x[i], 4, fp);
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text file that I have linked to it:

```
Hi, my name is Frank.  
I like pie.  
My car is black.
```

Comment: You will have to check if fopen fails.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen()`. Also, the size of `x[i]` is 5, you should have `fgets(x[i], 5, fp)`, or better yet, `fgets(x[i], sizeof(x[i]), fp)`.

Comment: works fine for me with an existing and readable "wageData.txt"; try using a debugger or at some `printf()`s to get more intormation

Comment: You also have to check if `fgets` fails `if (NULL==fgets(...)) {...}`

Comment: oops my bad sorry forks..should have checked the man page first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built and executed your code with your suggested data, and it executes without error.  However, you do not check that the call to `fopen()` is successful, and if `fp` is not a valid open file pointer, it does indeed abort.

I suspect in that case that the file was not opened; perhaps it was not in the current working path, was incorrectly named (POSIX file-systems for example are case sensitive), or was other wise locked (perhaps open elsewhere).

Equally it would be wise to check the success of `fgets()` so that it will work with files shorter then three lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("wageData.txt", "r+");
    if( fp != 0 )
    {
        char x[3][5];
        int i = 0;
        int j ;
        char* check = 0 ;
        while( i < 3 && fgets(x[i], 4, fp) != 0 ) 
        {
            i++;
        }

        for( j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", x[j]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "File not opened.\n" ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```